# Can't properly parse multipart/form-data inside Azure functions using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to parse multipart/form-data from my Azure function writing in Node.js, but the `context.req.body` is not binary, and if I try to parse a PDF (for example) it will loose information. Is there a way to bypass it? I've searched a LOT and it seems that this is a knowing issue.

```
module.exports.handler = (context) => {
  context.info(context.req.body) // This is a string, not a binary
}
```

I've also tried to change the `dataType` to `binary`, inside the functions.json, but it still keeps going as string, so I guess this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it's a known issue, see [Multipart/form-data processing via HttpTrigger doesn't work for Azure Functions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2009).

The suggested workaround for now is to use Base64 encoding, as described in [Image uploading with Azure Functions node.js and Angular 4](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/livedevopsinjapan/2017/10/07/image-uploading-with-azure-functions-node-js-and-angular-4/).

Comment: Really? That's really sad. I was moving all my infrastructure from AWS to Azure, now I'm giving it up.